# Converting REGEXP_REPLACE substitution to a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure this has been answered before, but after some searching I couldn't find anything that I really understood and I know very little about SQL. I am trying to convert the returned substitution of REGEXP_REPLACE into a date.

```
SELECT ..., REGEXP_REPLACE("References",'.*::(.*)','\1') AS "Pay Date", ...
```

The returned format of the substitution `\1` is `MM/D(D)/YYYY e.g. 12/3/2020 or 12/13/2020`.

My understanding is that you can call functions from within another function like most spreadsheet programs. `e.g. REXEXP_REPLACE(TO_DATE(...,...),...)` but was unable to cobble anything together that would work. I was kind of surprised I couldn't find a lot of examples of this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `to_date()` as:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE("References",'.*::(.*)', '\1'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense. I was trying to run to_date on the returned substitution, but I should have been using the regex_replace as the text of the to_date function. Thanks so much!